# AOP based object injection fails for class name starting with lower case

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am doing object injection using AOP.
There exists a class which starts with samllcase (testClass) wherein the object is not getting injected.

I converted the file name (legacy class) so that it starts with capital case (TestClass) and updated references in AOP.xml and spring-beans.xml containing the bean definitions and it it started to work as intended.

My question is that is there a specification at Spring / AOP to have class names to start with capital case? Any reference link will be appreciated .

Or
Am I missing something ?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was the case. Can you reproduce this behaviour using a standalone test case?

Comment: Which version of Spring?

Comment: I am using Spring 2.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot, but are you using annotations at all? When using annotations (e.g. @Component) the bean id of the bean created from the annotation is the classname with a lowercase first letter. Maybe what is happening is that the AOP processing does a reverse of this to go from bean id to class name so with a lower case first letter of the class, this reverse won't work.

Comment: I am using @Configurable annotation on the class containing the injected object.